# How to fix radius on particular spot using subdivision modifier

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

I'm trying to fix a spot on the mesh which has too much of a curve when I extrude downwards in the mesh.
So my first attempt was to add more loop cuts which fixed the radius but then it ruined the shape of the circle in the middle creating pinching. I also tried with edge crease. At first didn't select all the edge lines it did make a nice radius but it left artefacts on the edges. Only when I selected more edges it fixed up the artefacts but then I lost the shape of the radius and ended up as a rectangle. So whats the right way to approach this modelling technique?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose a (little) method to handle this kind of cases. About the radius, you just need to adjust the support vertices location (see below).

If a considered good square part needs two support edges to be ok at some reasonable subdivision level:

[image]

And if a round part if considered ok with the same subdivision level:

[image]

Then we can make the model starting with a grid and adjust the vertices amount of the bigger parts considering the amount for the smaller one:

[image]

Then, extrude/scale <kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>S</kbd> and make the rounded parts round <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>:

[image]

Move the support vertices:

[image]

Extrude:

[image]

Mark bevel weights and add bevel:

[image]

Add subdivision and shade smooth:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is also another perspective from what you demonstrated here, modelling in sections.  This is taken into consideration, very well layout for educational purposes! thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following topology:

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for the screen shot, can you please post another screen shot orthographic view?

Comment: done, please tell me if it's clear?

Comment: Whoa, sure is! Thanks!